# Hat man »zwei Eltern« oder »zwei Elternteile«?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonym

Auf meiner Website habe ich heute einen Beitrag veröffentlicht, der mit diesem Satz beginnt:

> Ein Mensch hat zwei Eltern, vier Großeltern, acht Urgroßeltern und so weiter.

Ein Kommentator hat daraufhin behauptet, kein Mensch habe zwei Eltern, sondern zwei Elternteile.

Wer hat recht?

Comment: Man kann sicherlich beides sagen, den genauen Unterschied in der Nutzung kann ich aber nicht erklären. "Ein Mensch hat zwei Eltern" ist auf jeden Fall nicht falsch, insofern hat der Kommentator schonmal nicht recht.

Comment: Bitte auf englisch taggen ;) Siehe dazu: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/7/which-language-should-tags-be-in

Comment: @Vogel612: Ich finde es doof in einen Forum der deutschen Sprache Etiketten einer anderen Sprache zu verwenden.

Comment: @Hubert das einzig dumme an der sache ist, dass die Etiketten von möglichst vielen Deutschlernenden auch gelesen und verstanden werden sollen. Und darum hat man sich darauf geeinigt Englisch zu etikettieren ;)

Comment: @Vogel612: Was ist mit Leuten, die kein Englisch können und Deutsch lernen wollen? Franzosen, Italiener, Russen, usw. Müssen die alle erst mal Englisch lernen bevor sie Deutsch lernen dürfen?? Und was ist mit Leuten deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist? Warum werde ich gezwungen eine andere Sprache zu verwenden, wenn ich mich in deutscher Sprache über die deutsche Sprache unterhalten möchte?

Comment: @HubertSchönalst Betonung auf **möglichst vielen**. Da Englisch auf dem besten Weg ist, zur *lingua franca* zu werden, und der Rest der Seite so oder so Englisch organisiert ist, hat sich die "Community" (oder eben Gemeinschaft) dazu entschieden, die Etiketten auf Englisch zu normieren. Dass es Leute gibt, die kein Englisch können, und Deutsch lernen wollen, ist in diesem Fall einfach niedriger gewichtet worden.

Comment: @Vogel612: Alles was du sagst stimmt schon, aber Tatsache ist auch, dass alle, die die Seite german.stackexchange.com besuchen, hierherkommen nicht um Englisch, sondern um Deutsch zu lernen. Die Leute kommen hierher, weil sie deutsche Begriffe lesen und verstehen wollen.

Comment: @Hubert wenn du so unzufrieden damit bist, dann stell dich einfach mal eine Frage auf [meta]. Da Antworten auch andere. Du müsstest aber auf Englisch fragen..

Comment: So lange man nicht nur ein Paar Großeltern hat!

Comment: zwei Eltern natürlich :)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Der andere Grund: Stack Exchange, wozu dieser Seite gehört, ist eine Amerikanische Firma.  Sie wollen bei wichtige Sachen mitlesen können, z.B. bei Konflikte. Sie können nur ein völlig Deutschsprachige Seite unterstützen, wann sie Deutschsprachige MitarbeiterInnen einstellen, wie sie z.B. für Russisch oder Spanisch gemacht haben.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Man kann definitiv beides sagen. Es gibt aber einen wichtigen Unterschied.
Der Singular von Eltern - [das Elter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Elter) - wird im Deutschen fast nie verwendet. Stattdessen wird meistens auf das Elternteil zurückgegriffen.

Comment: @Toscho Die Unterscheidung ist nicht fehlerhaft. Das Wort "Elter" ist nicht gebräuchlich, sondern wird höchstens in der Fachsprache verwendet. "Elternteil" ist die richtige Bezeichnung für den Singular von "Eltern".

Comment: @DominicDeCoco `Singular` ist ein grammatikalischer Terminus. Die Anwendung hier ist falsch, weil `Eltern` nicht der Plural von `Elternteil` ist, sondern `Elternteile`.

Comment: @Toscho Das stimmt natürlich. Was ich meinte ist, dass Elternteil in der Funktion der Einzahl von Eltern verwendet wird, da der eigentliche Singular "Elter" alles andere als gebräuchlich ist.

Answer (score 3):

Man sagt – und das zweifelt wohl keiner an –

> Mein**e** Eltern **sind** …

Das ist Plural. Also sind es mindestens zwei. Und zwar Mutter und Vater.

Um das Argument zu kräftigen, vergleiche man das mal mit beispielsweise "Meine Schulklasse ist …". Hier ist eine Menge an Personen in einem Wort, das im Singular steht, verschmolzen.

Und noch ein Beispiel:

> A: Wie viele deiner Großeltern leben noch?
>   B: Drei.

Oder wenn ich sage

> Meine Großeltern leben nebenan.

beziehe ich mich nicht auf alle meine Großeltern, sondern nur auf die entweder mütterlicherseits oder väterlicherseits.